# Drag a div around a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A total newbie here but could someone please review this code and let me know where I am going wrong?
What effect I am trying to achieve: i have 8 divs around the page, and i have another div inside the page, i want to move this div 'myDIV' aroud the page by dragging it , then i want to drag and drop this 'myDIV' into the 'ZE' div.

here is what i did

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
/*styling here*/

.myDIV {
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 370px;   
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-top: 38px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;

        /* gradients - second red border, first red border, top white space, blue lines */
    background-image:  -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .2), rgba(255,85,91, .2)), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .8), rgba(255,85,91, .8)), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0px, white 69px, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70px), -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(white 0px, white 18px, #A6FFED 19px, white 20px);
    background-image:  -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .2), rgba(255,85,91, .2)), -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .8), rgba(255,85,91, .8)), -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0px, white 69px, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70px), -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(white 0px, white 18px, #A6FFED 19px, white 20px);
    background-image:  -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .2), rgba(255,85,91, .2)), -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .8), rgba(255,85,91, .8)), -ms-linear-gradient(top, white 0px, white 69px, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70px), -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(white 0px, white 18px, #A6FFED 19px, white 20px);
    background-image:  -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .2), rgba(255,85,91, .2)), -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .8), rgba(255,85,91, .8)), -o-linear-gradient(top, white 0px, white 69px, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70px), -o-repeating-linear-gradient(white 0px, white 18px, #A6FFED 19px, white 20px);
    background-image:  linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .2), rgba(255,85,91, .2)), linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .8), rgba(255,85,91, .8)), linear-gradient(top, white 0px, white 69px, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70px), repeating-linear-gradient(white 0px, white 18px, #A6FFED 19px, white 20px);
    background-size: 1px, 1px, auto, auto 20px;
    background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat-y, no-repeat, repeat;
    background-position: 90% 0px, 10% 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.myDIV:first-line {
    line-height: 33px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.myDIV:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.avatar {
width : 40px;
height : 40px;
display: block;

}

.ZP {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #ccc;
 display: flex;              /* establish flex container */
    flex-direction: column;     /* stack flex items vertically */
    justify-content: center;    /* center items vertically, in this case */
    align-items: center;        /* center items horizontally, in this case */
 /*display: table-cell;

  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;*/
}

.ZE { 
height: 100px;
width: 500px; 

background-color: green; 
position: fixed;
overflow: hidden;

/* outer shadows  (note the rgba is red, green, blue, alpha) */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); 
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(23, 69, 88, .5);

/* rounded corners */
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px; 
border-radius: 7px;

/* gradients */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
color-stop(0%, green), color-stop(15%, green), color-stop(100%, #D7E9F5)); 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, green 0%, green 0%, #D5E4F3 130%); 
}


.ZE1 {
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 250px);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.ZE2 {
    top: 0;
    left: calc(85% - 250px);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.ZE3 {
    top: calc(50% - 50px);
    left: calc(100% - 300px);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.ZE4 {
    top: calc(100% - 100px);
    left: calc(85% - 250px);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.ZE5 {
    top: calc(100% - 100px);
    left: calc(50% - 250px);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.ZE6 {
    top: calc(100% - 100px);
    left: calc(15% - 250px);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.ZE7 {
    top: calc(50% - 50px);
    left: -200px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.ZE8 {
    top: 0;
    left: calc(15% - 250px);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <!--The above library(/socket.io/socket.io.js) will be generated by socket.io module of server -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="ZonePartage.js"></script>
<script src="ZoneCollaborative.js"></script>
<script src="Constante.js"></script>
<script src="ZoneEchange.js"></script>
<script src="Artifact.js"></script>
<script src="Serveur.js"></script>
<script src="User.js"></script>



</head>
<body id = view>


<script>
/* Events fired on the drag target */

document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
    // The dataTransfer.setData() method sets the data type and the value of the dragged data
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);

    // Output some text when starting to drag the p element
    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Started to drag the p element.";

    // Change the opacity of the draggable element
    event.target.style.opacity = "0.4";
});

// While dragging the p element, change the color of the output text
document.addEventListener("drag", function(event) {
  //  document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
});

// Output some text when finished dragging the p element and reset the opacity
document.addEventListener("dragend", function(event) {
    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Finished dragging the p element.";
    event.target.style.opacity = "1";
});


/* Events fired on the drop target */

// When the draggable p element enters the droptarget, change the DIVS's border style
document.addEventListener("dragenter", function(event) {
    if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE1" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
    }
    if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE2" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
    }
    if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE3" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
    }
    if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE4" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
    }
    if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE5" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
    }
    if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE6" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
    }
    if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE7" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
    }
    if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE8" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
    }
});

// By default, data/elements cannot be dropped in other elements. To allow a drop, we must prevent the default handling of the element
document.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});

// When the draggable p element leaves the droptarget, reset the DIVS's border style
document.addEventListener("dragleave", function(event) {
    if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE1" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "";
    }
     if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE2" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "";
    }
     if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE3" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "";
    }
     if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE4" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "";
    }
     if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE5" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "";
    }
     if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE6" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "";
    }
     if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE7" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "";
    }
     if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE8"
      ) {
        event.target.style.border = "";
    }
});

/* On drop - Prevent the browser default handling of the data (default is open as link on drop)
   Reset the color of the output text and DIV's border color
   Get the dragged data with the dataTransfer.getData() method
   The dragged data is the id of the dragged element ("drag1")
   Append the dragged element into the drop element
*/
document.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( event.target.className == "ZP" ) {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "";
        event.target.style.border = "";
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE1" ) {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "";
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE2" ) {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "";
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE3" ) {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "";
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE4" ) {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "";
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE5" ) {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "";
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE6" ) {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "";
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE7" ) {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "";
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    if ( event.target.className == "ZE ZE8" ) {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "";
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
});
</script>

<div class="out">

<div class="ZP"   style="text-align: center;"  id="demo">





</div>
<div class="ZE ZE1"   id="ze1" >

<img class="avatar"; src="avatar1.png"  />
<div class="myDIV myDIV1" class="ui-widget-content draggable" draggable="true" id="myDIV1" style="display: inline-block">

ARTEFACT1
</div>
</div>
<span
        style="left: 527.5px; top: 0px; width: 800px; height: 200px; transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1) rotate(180deg); opacity: 0;"
        class="back"></span>

<div class="ZE ZE2"  id="ze2" >
<img class="avatar"; src="avatar2.png" />

<div class="myDIV myDIV2" class="ui-widget-content draggable" draggable="true"  id="myDIV2">

ARTEFACT2
</div>

</div>
<span
        style="left: 1176.75px; top: 0px; width: 800px; height: 200px; transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1) rotate(180deg); opacity: 0;"
        class="back"></span>

<div class="ZE ZE3"  id="ze3" >
<img class="avatar"; src="avatar3.png" />

<div class="myDIV myDIV3" class="ui-widget-content draggable" draggable="true"  id="myDIV3">

ARTEFACT3
</div>

</div>
<span
        style="left: 1405px; top: 392.5px; width: 800px; height: 200px; transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1) rotate(270deg); opacity: 0;"
        class="back"></span>

<div class="ZE ZE4"   id="ze4" >
<img class="avatar"; src="avatar4.png"  />

<div class="myDIV myDIV4" class="ui-widget-content draggable" draggable="true"  id="myDIV4">

ARTEFACT4
</div>



</div>
<span
        style="left: 1176.75px; top: 785px; width: 800px; height: 200px; transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1) rotate(0deg); opacity: 0;"
        class="back"></span>
<div class="ZE ZE5" id="ze5" >
<img class="avatar"; src="avatar5.png"  />

<div class="myDIV myDIV5" class="ui-widget-content draggable" draggable="true"  id="myDIV5">

ARTEFACT5
</div>

</div>
    <span
        style="left: 527.5px; top: 785px; width: 800px; height: 200px; transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1) rotate(0deg); opacity: 0;"
        class="back"></span>

<div class="ZE ZE6" id="ze6" >
<img class="avatar"; src="avatar6.png"  />

<div class="myDIV myDIV6" class="ui-widget-content draggable" draggable="true"  id="myDIV6">

ARTEFACT6
</div>

</div>
<span
        style="left: -121.75px; top: 785px; width: 800px; height: 200px; transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1) rotate(0deg); opacity: 0;"
        class="back"></span>
<div class="ZE ZE7" id="ze7" >


<img class="avatar"; src="avatar7.png"  />
<div class="myDIV myDIV7" class="ui-widget-content draggable" draggable="true"  id="myDIV7">

ARTEFACT7
</div>
</div>
<span
        style="left: -350px; top: 392.5px; width: 800px; height: 200px; transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1) rotate(90deg); opacity: 0;"
        class="back"></span>
<div class="ZE ZE8" id="ze8" >
<img class="avatar"; src="avatar8.png" />
<div class="myDIV myDIV8" class="ui-widget-content draggable" draggable="true"  id="myDIV8">

ARTEFACT8
</div>

</div>
<span
        style="left: -121.75px; top: 0px; width: 800px; height: 200px; transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1) rotate(180deg); opacity: 0;"
        class="back"></span>

        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you are interested, there's already an existing solution for this in the jquery ui: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/ . You can combine this with droppable and selectable (see them in the menu) and you have that functionality that you are after in just a few lines of code :)

Comment: i didn't understant what you mean @Spluf

Comment: You are trying to drag & drop elements in your page, that functionality is already built in jqueryUI, so you can just use that in stead of trying to build it yourself. You can find examples on that link I provided earlier on how to use it. Go to https://jqueryui.com/draggable/ (for the draggable example) and on the left menu at the top you can also get to the droppable examples.

Comment: i tried the first exemple of gragging , i did copy and past for the code ! it is not working

Comment: I just tried it and it works, make sure you have the right jquery & jquery ui refferences. Here is the plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/Wq4sNcfIfh1NwU4MgAGv?p=preview

Comment: how could i have the right jquery & jquery ui refferences ? i want to work on my laptop with my Text editor

Comment: From what I see you are using the right versions, check your console to see if you don't have any errors and if everything got loaded, or copy the example again in a clean file and start from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery for this problem:

```
$(function() {
   $( "#myDIV" ).draggable();
});
```

Check out the jQueryAPI for further information:

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement colud be what you are looking for. Or even the sortable: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
  </script>` 
Tis is not workinh ! now i'm confused

Comment: And with $( ".myDIV" )? Please give us more information, what is not working? Do you get any JS errors in your Log?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this link 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop
hope this will help .

Answer (score 0):

You have jQuery UI. Let's use it:

```
(document).ready(function(){
    $('myDIV').draggable();
});
```

Comment: it didn't work ! i cant drag it ! :/ 

  `<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#myDIV" ).draggable();
  });

  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="myDIV" id="myDIV" >
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>`

Comment: are you try to drag your text?

Comment: i try to drag 'myDIV'

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not including jQuery UI.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Then it should look like this:

```
 $( function() {
$( "#myDiv" ).draggable();
```

} );